# Update custom membershipuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere. I'm using a custom membership provider and membership user with my own tables, which is appearing to be far too much hassle than it's worth. When updating a user record it appears that I need to update it's membership user instance as well, otherwise where I'm relying on data from membership user it isn't corresponding to the updated database.

I've created my own update membership user method, as the existing one only accepted it's own MembershipUser class:

```
public static void UpdateAccountUser(AccountUser accountUser)
    {
        // Custom MembershipUser
        ToMembershipUser user = new ToMembershipUser(
                    "AccountUserMembershipProvider",
                    accountUser.FirstName + " " + accountUser.LastName,
                    accountUser.ID,
                    accountUser.Email,
                    "",
                    "",
                    true,
                    false,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.MinValue,
                    DateTime.MinValue,
                    DateTime.MinValue,
                    DateTime.MinValue);

        // Fill additional properties
        user.ID = accountUser.ID;
        user.Email = accountUser.Email;
        user.FirstName = accountUser.FirstName;
        user.LastName = accountUser.LastName;
        user.Password = accountUser.Password;
        user.MediaID = accountUser.MediaID;
        user.Media = accountUser.Media;
        user.Identity = accountUser.Identity;
        user.CreatedAt = accountUser.CreatedAt;
        user.UpdatedAt = accountUser.UpdatedAt;

        UpdateCookie(user.Email);
    }
    private static void UpdateCookie(string email)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(email, true);
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        // Store UserData inside the Forms Ticket with all the attributes
        // in sync with the web.config
        var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                                      ticket.Name,
                                                      ticket.IssueDate,
                                                      ticket.Expiration,
                                                      true, // always persistent
                                                      email,
                                                      ticket.CookiePath);

        // Encrypt the ticket and store it in the cookie
        cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
        cookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration.AddHours(24);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }
```

Now obviously this is just creating a new instance and not updating the existing one, which doesn't allow me to see the updated details without logging out and logging back in. Any ideas?

Edit
So I managed to find an example of someone else using their own custom update method, but all they appear to be doing is updating the database not the MembershipUser itself. I'm already doing this?!

I attempted to instead just update the FormsAuthenticationCookie and then when calling Membership.GetUser() I at least pass an updated User.Identity.Name, but to no avail, still old data even though database is updated. I've ran out of ideas...

This could possibly be a repeat of yesterday's question [MembershipUser not getting updated result from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020582/membershipuser-not-getting-updated-result-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out the MembershipUser wasn't updating due to every time I calling GetUser() the query involved was using FirstOrDefault(). Turns out this caches the result rather than retrieving a fresh result. By adding AsNoTracking() to the query itself I now get the updated result, without having to even call UpdateUser().